# Cannot login using php through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a PHP based web-interface, with a login system.

But for some reason when I hit login, it seems to get to the login.php and return a response back.

But the thing is, the response is not what I need to have, and furthermore logging in is still not happening.

***The HTML based login form (Within a modal):***

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo Utils::resolveInternalUrl('backend/Login.php') ?>" id="loginForm">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="loginUsername">Username:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="loginUsername" id="loginUsername" />
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="loginPassword">Password:</label> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword"/>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

***Javascript/jQuery related to login:***

```
var form = $('#loginForm');

form.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        'data': form.serialize(),
        'type': $(this).attr('method'),
        'url': $(this).attr('action'),
        'dataType': 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
          alert("Success: " + data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
           alert("Error: " + error)
        }
      })
  })
```

***PHP backend, related to login:***

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $database = Database::getDefaultInstance();

        if(isset($_POST['loginUsername']) && isset($_POST['loginPassword'])) {
            $connection = $database->getConnection();
            $username = $_POST['loginUsername'];
            $password = $_POST['loginPassword'];

            echo $username . ":" . $password;

            $stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM banmanagement.users;");

            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                session_start();

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['sessionId'] = Utils::randomNumber(32);

                echo json_encode("Successfully logged in as ${username}.");
                exit;
            } else {
                echo json_encode("No user exists with the name \"${username}\".");
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode("Username and/or password is not provided.");
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode("Submit method is not POST.");
        exit;
    }
```

***The result of it:***
[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBzHy.png)

**Edit:**
Changed SQL query to: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banmanagement.users WHERE username=:username;`

**Edit 2:**
Per suggestion, I have used `var_dump` the output `var_dump($_POST)` is: `array(0) { }`.

Comment: Why are you using `'dataType': 'JSON'`?

Comment: Well.. Not really a reason, it what's taught to me.
Anything wrong with it, if so why?

Comment: The function is able to detect the datatype automatically from the response headers. It's not wrong, but unusual to set this.

Comment: Today I've learnt something new, Thank you.

Comment: Well, according to doc it should be ok. In fact I am more looking your PHP code and it looks messy. The way you are looking if the user exists seems strange to me because you initialize the session on `$stmt->fetch()` not on checking if the username and password (not encoded?) are valid.

Comment: Please see the edit, I hope that might be something better?

Comment: declare the type and url params as variable outside of $.ajax - I've had problems using $(this) inside the ajax call rather than outside

Comment: The username and password doesn't get to the php page, but it is send.

Comment: In the .ajax call should the keys be quoted like they are?

Comment: With or without quotes doesn't seem to matter, because it gets sent to the php page.

Answer (score -1):

```
$stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM banmanagement.users;");
```

I'm assuming you're using PDO on the backend.  If so, you don't need the semicolon in your query.  That's why your fetch is failing.

```
$stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM banmanagement.users");
```

Ok, so that wasn't it.  I was reading the wrong braces.  Have you tried `var_dump($_POST)` to see what, if anything, is being sent?

Comment: The error can't be in that part of the code.  If the username and password would have been set, and that code would have run, the response received would have been either "Successfully logged in as..." or "No user exists with..."

Comment: Output of `var_dump($_POST)` is: `array(0) { }`, so no data is sent.